# Cannot remove safely usb external hard drive, it mounts again

Tags: mount, external-hdd, unmount

I have an external usb hard drive, however when I try to safely remove it, the device turns off and then the device mounts itself again. I've tried to do

```
sudo udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

However, the device gets mounted again!

Any solutions? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Refer to my answer on another question [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/485913/295286). There is command to actually power off the device

Comment: I have already used udisk --detach, as i mentioned the disk gets mounted again

Comment: Can you safely remove it in nautilus? If yes you can type this command so it doesn’t auto remount: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false`

Comment: I can, however after 1 or 2 seconds the device gets mounted again. After doing the gsettings command, it appears on nautilus but doesn't get mounted... however it appears again

Answer (score 0):

For removing your device, you should un-mount it:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

in case it failed to un-mount, you should force it by add `-f` option:

```
sudo umount -f /dev/sdb
```